# Keystore certificate works at Eclipse but Tomcat no

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, keystore

I have an application running in Eclipse, works fine, connect and get a response from webservice that needs a certificate.
But when I deploy and run in Tomcat, I got a error of valid certification:

```
java.lang.Exception
Message
; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:      
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid 
certification path to requested target
```

In my tomcat:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
port="8443" keystoreFile="webapps/.keystore" keystorePass="123456"
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

and in my application, I have another keystore to webservice:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", SIC.jks);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePassword);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePassword);
```

I tried import certificate to cacerts from keytool and nothing...

I don't have any one idea and my time is over in my job...What can I do to resolve that?

I tried everything I guess...works at Eclipse but on deploy tomcat, I got that error above.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions
1. Specify the entire path for the keystoreFile. Eg

```
/opt/webapps/.keystore
```

2. Do not use special characters "**@**" in the password.

Comment: Thank you for your help and about my problem that my application doesn't find another keystore inside set property? Any suggestion?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not follow the question. Did you try the above suggestions ?